# session not unsetting and if tried to unset it does not show at all

Tags: php

I know this may be a silly issue but for some reason it is not working for me

I have the controller where I am writing the code

```
if ($result == true){
        $_SESSION['msgSuccess'] = true;
header('Location:dt-currency.php');
```

and in my view

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['msgSuccess'])) { ?>
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <p><?php echo "data updated"; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                            unset($_SESSION['msgSuccess']);
                        } ?>
```

after writing unset the alert is not showing at all so please assist me in unsetting the session so that it does not show on refresh.

Comment: are you getting $_SESSION['msgSuccess'] in another file

Comment: as of now I am including the view below the controller so have not checked it.. and yes it is showing on another file

Comment: tested working fine

Comment: does the session disappear on reload ? as it is not disappearing for me

Comment: yes i tested in my local, you have to check about session start issue in both page

Comment: session_start() is there..dont know the issue man..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146149/discussion-between-ahmed-ginani-and-dhaval-chheda).